# Getting Google Sheets API erros in user's primary language

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-translate, google-api-nodejs-client

We are trying to handle the google sheets cell count limit overflow issue, where we are validating the error message, status text and status code to check the issue type since google APIs are not providing a common error message like Exception errors message.

If the primary language of the user's gmail account is set to some other language than english we are getting error message in the selected language but not in english.

Example: Getting error in German

```
"{"body":{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Diese Aktion würde die Anzahl der Zellen in der Arbeitsmappe auf mehr als die maximal zulässigen 10000000 Zellen erhöhen.","errors":[{"message":"Diese Aktion würde die Anzahl der Zellen in der Arbeitsmappe auf mehr als die maximal zulässigen 10000000 Zellen erhöhen.","domain":"global","reason":"badRequest"}],"status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}},"message":{"content":"Diese Aktion würde die Anzahl der Zellen in der Arbeitsmappe auf mehr als die maximal zulässigen 10000000 Zellen erhöhen.","status":"Error"}}"
```

Since we are handling it for english language only in our code base, its failing for other language users. Is there a way to get all the error messages from Sheets API only in english regardless of user's primary language ?

Expected result:
Regardless of the user's primary language error message should be returned in English only